# WooCommerce change loading spinner icon

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, spinner

IM trying to change the WooCommerce loading spinner icon. It's defined in the woocommerce.css:

```
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay::before {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -.5em;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    content: '';
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    background: url(../images/icons/loader.svg) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}
```

I've tried changing the loader.svg with a custom css:

```
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay::before {
     background: url(http://www.localhost.de/wp-content/uploads/custom-loader.svg) center center !important;
}
```

But the icon will not change. So I've googled a bit and found this here:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_loader_url', 'custom_loader_icon', 10, 1 );
function custom_loader_icon() {
    return __( get_home_path() . 'wp-content/uploads/custom-loader.svg', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

But the loading spinner icon is still the same. What can I do to change it? I don't know what I should try now...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following code css rules work in Woocommerce last version. I have embedded them in the `wp_head` hook as it's easy for testing:

You will use [this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEKwt.gif) for testing, that you will put in your active child theme under an "`img`" directory, renaming the file `my_spinner.gif`.

If you use a theme instead of a child theme, you will use `get_template_directory_uri()` function instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` in the code.

The code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_ajax_spinner', 1000 );
function custom_ajax_spinner() {
    ?>
    <style>
    .woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,
    .woocommerce .loader:before {
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -.5em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        animation: none;
        background-image:url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/img/my_spinner.gif"; ?>') !important;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        line-height: 1;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, one tip for others. Some checkout forms can be a bit long and you won't see the spinner. Update the position to "fixed" so that it is always visible.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 2):

I think CSS only is enough

```
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,
.woocommerce .loader:before {
  background-image:url('path/to/your/image.gif');
}
```

it will work fine

Comment: Do you know what CSS to use for 2023, Woocommerce 8.1.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the custom spinner in Wordpress Media, lets say the name of the file is my-spinner.gif  and later check the route of the gif image. Example: https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/my-spinner.gif

For Woocommerce 8.1.1 is working.

Add CSS in your theme like this:

```
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,
.woocommerce .loader:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  background-image: url("https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/my-spinner.gif") !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code. Assuming your `custom-loader.svg` is at root of "uploads" directory.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_loader_url', 'custom_loader_icon', 10, 1 );
function custom_loader_icon($str_replace) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $str_replace = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/wp-content/uploads/custom-loader.svg'
    return $str_replace;
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Not working sorry. It's like the same I did but I just returned the URL directly