# How to display a message on the checkout page after clicking on the proceed to payment button?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I am using Woocommerce. I have to display a message on the checkout page after clicking on the proceed to payment button.

As of now, I am getting the preloader. How do I display a message like "You are redirecting on payment gateway".

I am using [WooCommerce change loading spinner icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419831/woocommerce-change-loading-spinner-icon/53450141#53450141) answer code for the Ajax preloader. I have just changed the background image url to:

```css
background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEKwt.gif') !important;
```

Below code for displaying the message after clicking on proceed to payment:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'order_processed_with_pending_status', 10, 3 );
function order_processed_with_pending_status( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
     echo"You are redirecting on payment gateway";
}
```

Would you help me out with the correct hook?

Comment: This is simply not possible as by default checkout "place order" button action is not Ajax driven, but trigger a normal submit (Post).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Is there any other option to solve this issue?

Comment: Think about it… When customer click on "Place order", data is posted, customer is redirected either to  payment gateways then Order received page or directly to Order received page. So there is no option to display anything in checkout page. Instead you can display something in Order received (thankyou) Page using [`woocommerce_thankyou` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_thankyou)